# Find worksheet index using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to get index of worksheet using win32com module. I could not find any suitable function to do it. I am hoping something like below exists:

```
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), workbook))
ws_index = wb.Worksheets.index(ws)
```

Please let me know how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using another module: openpyxl. It can easily be installed through the command line using pip.
Then do:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(old_filename)
sheet_name = "" # Put whatever name you are searching for into the string
sheet_names = workbook.sheetnames
index = sheet_names.index(sheet_name)
print(index)
```

'index' will be the sheet number you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I have to use win32com in my application.. Is there any way to do it using win32com functions?

Comment: Not really, I am afraid this is the only working method I know about...

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet` objects have [an `Index` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.index), so if `ws` is already a `Worksheet` then you can simply do this:

```py
index = ws.Index
```

In case `ws` is not the `Worksheet` itself but just its name as a string (you didn't specify that), you can fetch the `Worksheet` first:

```py
index = wb.Worksheets(ws).Index
```